# How do I turn all my cards into gems at once?

Tags: steam, steam-holiday-auction

In order to bid on stuff I need to turn my cards and items into gems, instead of doing it one at a time, is there a way I can turn them all into gems at the same time?

Comment: Sell your cards on the Market and buy gems, you'll get more for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There dosen't seem to be a way to do that. You just have to go through card by card.